# Performance counters and threading

Tags: c#

I am creating some custom performance counters.  I will be creating tasks on a thread pool and incrementing/decrementing the counters from within multiple worker threads.

Do I need to give each thread a new counter object?  Is it safe to share a performance counter object cross-thread (for increment/decrement)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PerformanceCounter class already uses a threadsafe wrapper, an internal class named SharedPerformanceCounter.  It uses Interlocked.Increment() to increment a counter value for example.

There's no need to lock yourself.

Comment: Yah, I ended up reflectoring in there and saw that.  Then I read the help, and it reads that only the static methods are thread safe.  So, I guess now I'm stuck with a philosophical dilemma:  Since the documentation doesn't guarantee safety, should I treat the current wrapper as an implementation detail, ignore it, and create thread-specific instances, or should I treat it as a documentation error and proceed with shared counters?  given what I see in the code, I think I'm safe, but 15 years of software engineering has jaded me, so I might go conservative.

Comment: If you want a guarantee with a warranty you'll need to call Microsoft.

Comment: Yah, I know, I'm not expecting that here.  Just sounding out what I'm thinking.