# How can I measure the time of a thread in c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance

I want to measure the time that a C# routine needs. Because there are many other threads I only want to count the time of this one thread. In Java I can use `getCurrentThreadCpuTime`.

How can I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934497/how-can-i-get-cpu-usage-and-or-ram-usage-of-a-thread-in-c-sharp-managed-code

Comment: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getthreadtimes

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [PerformanceCounters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx).  They are quite complex and can be a bit of a pain to set up, but are robust in what they offer for metrics.  A couple of things that might help:

[Performance counters and threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061196/performance-counters-and-threading)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adamhems/archive/2008/12/04/using-custom-performance-counters-to-measure-multi-threaded-operation-durations.aspx

Comment: I can not see how this should measure for the current thread only.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You cannot measure the accumulated time **ON THE CPU** for a particular `thread`.
The most accurate thing you could do would be to spin off a separate `process` for each of your tasks, and then measure the CPU time for the process (which actually can be done in .Net)... but that's overkill.

If you need help on how to do that, you should ask another question specifically for that.

Answer (score -3):

You can use Stopwatch for that. It would be the simplest way to get that.

```
    public void Worker()
    {
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        stopwatch.Start();

        ///Do your wwork here

        var timeElapsed = stopwatch.Elapsed;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I got your question wrong, so what about this? It does not work if you use thread sleep. Sorry if this still is not what you're looking for.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Collections.Concurrent;

    namespace ConsoleApplication2
    {
        class Program
        {
            static ConcurrentDictionary<int, ProcessThread> threadIdsMapping = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, ProcessThread>();


            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Thread oThread = new Thread(
                    delegate()
                    {
                        threadIdsMapping.GetOrAdd(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, GetProcessThreadFromWin32ThreadId(null));

                        long counter = 1;

                        while (counter < 1000000000)
                        {
                            counter++;
                        }
                    });

                oThread.Start();
                oThread.Join();

                Console.WriteLine(threadIdsMapping[oThread.ManagedThreadId].TotalProcessorTime);
                Console.WriteLine(threadIdsMapping[oThread.ManagedThreadId].UserProcessorTime);
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now - threadIdsMapping[oThread.ManagedThreadId].StartTime);

                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            public static ProcessThread GetProcessThreadFromWin32ThreadId(int? threadId)
            {
                if (!threadId.HasValue)
                {
                    threadId = GetCurrentWin32ThreadId();
                }

                foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses())
                {
                    foreach (ProcessThread processThread in process.Threads)
                    {
                        if (processThread.Id == threadId) return processThread;
                    }
                }

                throw new Exception();
            }

            [DllImport("Kernel32", EntryPoint = "GetCurrentThreadId", ExactSpelling = true)]
            public static extern Int32 GetCurrentWin32ThreadId();
        }
    }
```

Comment: -1 that's not what OP asked.

Comment: You are measuring an operation here, not a thread, so this answer is not what OP is looking for.

Comment: OP asked to get the execution of a *specific thread*, you're simply measuring the time it takes for a series of operations to execute. This has nothing to do with measuring a particular thread. This is similar, but not what he asked for.

Comment: This seems to count the time of all parallel threads and not the CPU time of the single thread.

Comment: This simply measures the time between two operations, it doesn't measure how much time a single thread spent doing anything.

Comment: @PeterRitchie I don't get you. You don't have any way, as of today of getting the time a thread took to complete using a simple method/property, so my example is a very valid implementation, and if you have a better way of doing it, let us know, down voting my answer does not help the OP AFAIK.